# M, V, C arrays vs require array inside Controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

What is the Sencha's way of preloading the dependencies?

Inside controller, is it better to put views, stores in arrays like this:

```
views: ['Full.Path.To.View', 'Full.Path.To.View'],
stores: ['Full.Path.To.Store', 'Full.Path.To.Store']
```

or just inside `requires`:

```
requires: ['Full.Path.To.View', 'Full.Path.To.View', 'Full.Path.To.Store', 'Full.Path.To.Store']
```

In some cases (when I want `Ext.syncRequire()`) works only the second option so I wanted your opinion. So, this is being called inside `Controller`, not inside app.js in `Ext.application`.

Thank you!

EDIT:

This is my solution and vision of how it should be:

```
var views = ['MyApp.view.Login.LoginForm', 'MyApp.view.Main.Index'];
var models = ['MyApp.model.Company'];
var stores = ['MyApp.store.Tables'];
var senchaData = ['Ext.field.Text', 'Ext.Button'];

var dependencies = [].concat(views, models, stores, senchaData);

Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: dependencies,
    config: {

        refs: {
            loginForm: '#loginForm',
            loginButton: '#loginForm #loginButton'
        },

        control: {
            loginButton: {
                tap: 'onLogin'
            }
        }

    }...
```

Comment: can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I decied to edit my answer. See my edit please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand how controller dependencies get resolved by the classmanager because that makes the difference.

*Note: Last time I dig into the controller classes was with version ExtJS4.2 so something might have change slightly.*

These arrays (models,views,controllers) have some benefits. 
One benefit is cleaner code due to the different arrays a second is that the controller can predict the namespace of each class base on the app namespace and the array. You have to know that these arrays get resolved a definition time!

Now these three arrays are nice but the classmanager didn't know them that is why the `Ext.app.Controller` inject a appropriate hooks for doing so. The hook get triggered when the class get extended and will require all classes found in one of the four array (models,stores,views,controllers). This force the classmanager to load these classes immediately.

Note that the `Ext.app.Application` is the only one that initializes the controllers, but since ExtJS4.2 it is possible to do it your own with only little effort.

That is all I can say based on your info. If this doesn't help please be more precise in which case loading fails.

**Edit**

Why not define it this way? It is better to read, isn't it?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: ['Login.LoginForm', 'Main.Index'],
    models: ['Company'],
    stores: ['Tables'],
    requires: ['Ext.field.Text', 'Ext.Button'];
    //...
}
```

Comment: I've learned a lot from this. You can check my question again because I've put my solution. I'll mark your question as answer. +1 And you've helped me a lot of times so... A really big thank you!

Comment: @NullCod3 You're welcome;) I will comment your question according your last edit

Comment: It is but it doesn't work if I load the Controller dynamically with `Ext.syncRequire('MyApp.controller.MyController');`.

Comment: @NullCod3 That is because the `Ext.app.Application` instance get bypassed, which initializes the controllers. Try this `Ext.Loader.syncRequire('FullControllerName', function(){applicationInstance.getController('FullControllerName')}, scope);` - this will require the class and after that fetch it via the application which will initialize it.

Comment: How the f did you know that? XD I mean, I've read almost the whole documentation and how in the world could I've know that?

Comment: And what do you think about my way? I mean, I don't think it's the wrong way and it's still seems clean.

Comment: @NullCod3 Well, you have to understand how the sencha classystem works after that readng the sourcecode is enough. The time I started (ExtJS 2.x) most parts where magic for me too ;)
Your way work, but you have some overhead by combining the arrays and you need to write the fully qualified classname for each. But you can always change it to the framework way without that much effort,which is good because I recommend you to always find a 'native' way. That may save you from huge migrations one day sencha update this. So yes it is possible to go with that, but I don't recommend it.